# Change column position of data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am learning to use the data.table package. One of the things I am trying to do is move the last column ("x") to the first column. Here is how I do it for a data frame:

```
DF <- cbind(x, DF[1:ncol(DF)]) #Rearrange columns
```

I read up on setcolorder and tried this, but I get an error

```
setcolorder(DT, c("x", 1: (length(DT)-1) ) )
```

Does anyone know a better solution?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### Option 1

Maybe you can use `setdiff`:

```
DT <- data.table(A = 1:2, B = 3:4, X = 5:6)
DT
#    A B X
# 1: 1 3 5
# 2: 2 4 6
setcolorder(DT, c("X", setdiff(names(DT), "X")))
DT
#    X A B
# 1: 5 1 3
# 2: 6 2 4
```

---

#### Option 2

Using a modified version of your approach:

```
setcolorder(DT, c("X", names(DT)[1:(length(DT)-1)]))
```

or

```
setcolorder(DT, c(length(DT), 1:(length(DT)-1)))
```

*Why the error in your approach? You were trying to include both column names and numeric column indices. Use one or the other, but not both.*

---

#### Option 3

I've written a function called `moveme` (which for the time being you can find [at this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/7183841) or [at my blog](http://news.mrdwab.com/2013/08/28/an-r-function-like-order-from-stata/)). You enter a string of "move" commands, separated by semicolons. This lets you shuffle around your columns pretty flexibly:

```
DT <- data.table(matrix(1:20, ncol = 10, dimnames = list(NULL, LETTERS[1:10])))
DT
#    A B C D  E  F  G  H  I  J
# 1: 1 3 5 7  9 11 13 15 17 19
# 2: 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20

setcolorder(DT, moveme(names(DT), "E, F first; B last; H, I before G"))
# DT
#     E  F A C D  H  I  G  J B
# 1:  9 11 1 5 7 15 17 13 19 3
# 2: 10 12 2 6 8 16 18 14 20 4
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize I could not include both column names and numeric column indices.

Comment: @Ananda, great function thanks for this. FYI, on your blog, the command `setcolorder(DT, names(mydf), moveme(names(mydf), "your move command"))` is not entirely correct. The first `names(mydf)` should be deleted

Comment: @simon_icl, thanks for that. Posted but didn't check what I posted, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

I think the following syntax will work if you want x in the first column

```
DF <- cbind（x,DF)
```

Or if you want it in any column like n

```
DF.combine <- cbind(DF[,1:(n-1)], x, DF[,n:ncol(DF)])# n should >1
```

Comment: this will needlessly copy the `data.table` around and that's discouraged